# Using button on collapsed Bootstrap navbar to toggle display of a specific div hidden with class="hidden-xs"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a complex search form that I want to hide by default on mobile browsers, instead displaying an icon in the navbar that toggles its display.

The div containing the search form is hidden by default on mobiles using `class="hidden-xs"`

What I wanted to do was have `$("#search").fadeToggle()` but this doesn't do the trick, in fact it doesn't appear to do anything.

Instead I am partly there by using `$("#search").removeClass('hidden-xs')` but this obviously doesn't toggle, or give a fade effect. Am I missing something obvious? The search form is quite complex and I do not want it to be displayed in the navbar even on large screens.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZNUBx/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with this :

**fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/ZNUBx/2/

**JS :**

```
$("#search-button").click( function(){
    $("#search").removeClass('hidden-xs').stop().hide().fadeIn();
});
```

**Update:** [asker demand][see comment] with hide event

*jsfiddle :* http://jsfiddle.net/ZNUBx/3

*Js:*

```
$("#search-button").on('click', function(){
    if(  $("#search").hasClass('hidden-xs')   )
    {
        $("#search").removeClass('hidden-xs').hide().fadeToggle();
    } else {
        $("#search").addClass('hidden-xs');
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This now shows it with a fade, but the second click and subsequent clicks just quickly fade it out and back in again (tested in Chrome and FF on Windows and Chrome on Android)

Comment: Oh cool, that simple, thanks. I'll accept that as the answer, but did you want to edit that in to avoid confusion for anyone who might find this? Cheers.